# HPe5406zl switch - stops routing after 2-4 days of uptime

Tags: switch, hp, hardware

I'm kind of at a loss for ideas on this one so any suggestions would be great.

We have an HPe5406zl switch that stops responding after about 2-4 days of uptime. When I mean stops routing it starts to go down and you can ping local network devices but not google. then google comes back up and something else stops working. A few hours later 90% of the network is unable to even ping the default gateway.
this switch is our L3 device so unless it needs to leave the company networks it doesn't hit a router.

It seems random on what devices/areas of the network are affected. When it goes down hard the front of the switch looks like its still working normally (blink patterns) but the only resolution is a full reboot. It will still allow console access. Next time this happens I’ll pull a “show tech” log from it but I’m hoping to resolve this before then.

The entire chassis has been replaced (including management card) and only 3 blades remain from the old unit that was doing this same thing. Old unit was the same model and experienced the same issue. With the assumption of hardware it was replaced.

Has anyone experienced this before or has any ideas?

Most my experience is with Cisco at this point so this has me kind of stumped but all I can assume is that its some kind of configuration.

There’s under 15 VLANs on this switch and all though STP is enabled there is no redundant paths between switches.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [updating firmware](https://h10145.www1.hp.com/Downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J8699A&lang=en,en&cc=us,us&prodSeriesId=1827663) if you haven't already...

```
HP-5406zl# sh version
Image stamp:    /ws/swbuildm/K_rel_hartford_qaoff/code/build/btm(K_rel_hartford_qaoff)
                Jan  7 2013 17:07:51
                K.15.09.0012
                635
Boot Image:     Primary
```

Take a look at CPU utilization as well. You may either be running into a resource issue or a straight-up bug.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the suggestion ewwhite. Its currently running the latest firmware (verified yesterday). I t hink that some kind of buffer is overloading so i'll start monitoring the performance. If a bug was causing something to be dumped into ram its logical that it could take 2-5 days to cap out the ram ect. I'll let you know if I find anything further.

thanks again